# Universal bundles for monoids versus groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

Dold and Lashof compare their construction for a monoid M to Milnor's
when M is a group G. They give an explicit comparison for the first stage of the constructions. Somewhere I've seen the general n-stage comparison formula - anyone remember where?

Comment: For groupoids, there were Buffet, Jean-Philippe; Lor, Jean-Claude
Une construction d'un universal pour une classe assez large de Γ-structures.(French)
C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B270(1970), A640–A642; and Homotopy and integrability.
Haefliger, André
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 197
Springer, Berlin, 1971, pp. 133–163.

Comment: Thanks - several relevant papers have been `forgotten''